# What's wrong with my pseudo random number generator?

Tags: c, random

I am having some trouble with my random number generator.  How my program works is that the player is given a set of ninja, each with a stealth score.  To progress, a ninja needs to pass a "stealth check".  How they pass is a RNG will pull any whole number between 0 and the ninja's stealth score.  If the RNG pulls a 0, they fail the check.  The problem is, some of the ninjas have a stealth score of 1.  This results in them always failing the check.  After I isolated and tested the RNG separately, this is still the case.  I also noticed it doesn't seem to be able to pull from the stealth score itself.  For example, a ninja with a stealth score of 3 never pulls 3, only 0, 1, and 2.  So, how do I fix this RNG?

```
int stealth_check(struct ninja student[4]){
    int stealth_pass;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        stealth_pass = rand() % student[i].stealth;
        printf("%d\n\n", stealth_pass);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The remainder of the division of **any** integer by 1 is 0, by 2 is at most 1, and by 3 is at most 2, I don't understand what your doubts are.

Comment: `rand() % student[i].stealth;` --> `rand() % (student[i].stealth + 1u);`.  Mind the `()` and `u`.

Answer (score 2):

Add 1 to student[i].stealth before you use it in the modulus.

Comment: I tried that, but Ninja number 3 still always pulls 0s.  I tried this multiple times, both ninja 1 and ninja 3 have stealth of 1, but while this fixes ninja 1's problem, ninja 3 still pulls 0s and only 0s.

Comment: Are you initializing the random number generator to a different seed every time? rand() is a pseudo-random number generator. It will generate the same series of numbers every run unless you change the seed.